SocialUser Data Arrives Undefined in Angular Facebook Login Process
I am trying to log in to Facebook using the @abacritt/angularx-social-login library in my Angular project. However, SocialUser data comes as undefined. My relevant codes are as follows:
**SocialUser:
**
export declare class SocialUser {
    provider: string;
    id: string;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    authToken: string;
    idToken: string;
    authorizationCode: string;
    response: any;
}

**login.component.ts:
**
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent extends BaseComponent {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private socialAuthService: SocialAuthService
  ) {
    super(spinner);
    socialAuthService.authState.subscribe(async (user: SocialUser) => {
      console.log(user);
      this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
      switch (user.provider) {
        case "GOOGLE":
          await userService.googleLogin(user, () => {});
          break;
        case "FACEBOOK":
          await userService.facebookLogin(user, () => {
            console.log(user);
          });
          break;
        default:
      }
    });
    this.authService.identityCheck();
    this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
  }

  async login(usernameOrEmail: string, password: string) {
    this.showSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
    await this.userService.login(usernameOrEmail, password, () => {
      this.authService.identityCheck();
      this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        const returnUrl: string = params["returnUrl"];
        if (returnUrl) this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
      });
      this.hideSpinner(SpinnerType.BallAtom);
    });
  }

  facebookLogin() {
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(FacebookLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID);
  }
}

**user.service.ts:
**
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService, private toastrService: CustomToastrService) { }

  async create(user: User): Promise<Create_User> {
    const observable: Observable<Create_User | User> = this.httpClientService.post<Create_User | User>({
      controller: "users",
    }, user);
    return await firstValueFrom(observable) as Create_User;
  }

  async login(userNameOrEmail: string, password: string, callBackFunction?: () => void): Promise<any> {
    const observable: Observable<any | TokenResponse> = this.httpClientService.post<any | TokenResponse>({
      controller: "users",
      action: "login"
    }, { userNameOrEmail, password });
    const tokenResponse: TokenResponse = await firstValueFrom(observable) as TokenResponse;
    if (tokenResponse) {
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", tokenResponse.token.accessToken);
      this.toastrService.message("Giriş Yapıldı", "İşlem Başarılı", {
        messageType: ToastrMessageType.Success,
        position: ToastrPosition.TopRight
      });
    }
    callBackFunction();
  }

  async googleLogin(user: SocialUser, callBackFunction?: () => void): Promise<any> {
    const observable: Observable<SocialUser | TokenResponse> = this.httpClientService.post<SocialUser | TokenResponse>({
      controller: "users",
      action: "google-login"
    }, user);
    const tokenResponse: TokenResponse = await firstValueFrom(observable) as TokenResponse;
    if (tokenResponse) {
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", tokenResponse.token.accessToken);
      this.toastrService.message("Authentication with Google successful", "Successful", {
        messageType: ToastrMessageType.Success,
        position: ToastrPosition.TopRight
      });
    }
    callBackFunction();
  }

  async facebookLogin(user: SocialUser, callBackFunction?: () => void): Promise<any> {
    const observable: Observable<SocialUser | TokenResponse> = this.httpClientService.post<SocialUser | TokenResponse>({
      controller: "users",
      action: "facebookLogin"
    }, user);
    const tokenResponse: TokenResponse = await firstValueFrom(observable) as TokenResponse;
    if (tokenResponse) {
      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", tokenResponse.token.accessToken);
      this.toastrService.message("Authentication with Facebook successful", "Successful", {
        messageType: ToastrMessageType.Success,
        position: ToastrPosition.TopRight
      });
    }
    callBackFunction();
  }
}

During the Facebook login process, the user object appears as undefined and therefore I cannot retrieve user information. How can I solve this problem?
Technologies I use:
Angular
@abacritt/angularx-social-login
appID and clientID created through the Facebook Developer application
Am I making any configuration or code errors? Can you help me?
Thanks.
For the Facebook login process, I configured the @abacritt/angularx-social-login library in my Angular project. I followed the steps below:
Creating an App in Facebook Developer Console:
I created an app via Facebook Developer Console and got the appID.
Adding and Configuring the Library to the Project:
I added @abacritt/angularx-social-login library to my project.
I made the necessary configurations in the app.module.ts file and added the appID for FacebookLoginProvider.
LoginComponent and UserService Settings:
I used SocialAuthService service in LoginComponent and created authState subscription.
I wrote a method for Facebook login in UserService and sent a request to the backend API.
My expectation:
When I click on the Facebook login button, the Facebook login page opens, and after the user logs in, the SocialUser object in the authState is filled and contains the user's information.
Happening:
The Facebook login page opens properly and the user logs in. However, the SocialUser object comes as undefined in the authState and I cannot retrieve the user information.
